# Reproducing Linux stat command in C

Tags: c, stat

I'm writing my own version of the stat command and I am having difficulty getting the correct output for the `Device` field.

When I run the Linux `stat` command on an empty file in the working directory I get:

```
Device: 801h/2049d
```

To replicate this I tried to extract from the `stat` structure, the `st_dev` field.

But printing `st_dev` gives me

```
Device: 801
```

I am missing the `h` at the end and I am not sure where the `2049d` comes from.

Is the first part just a formatting problem? I am printing in `hex` format. And how can I extract `2049d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since (hexadecimal) `0x801 == 2049` (decimal), you can get the output you're after from:

```
printf("Device: %xh/%dd\n", st.st_dev, st.st_dev);
```

The `h` in the format is the `h` that appears at the end of `801h`; the `%x` means 'print number in hex'.  Similarly, the `%d` means print in decimal, and the trailing `d` is the `d` in `2049d`.

Incidentally, on Linux and other POSIX platforms, you can also avoid repeating the `st.st_dev` argument.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Device: %1$xh/%1$dd\n", 0x801);
    return 0;
}
```

This also produces:

```
Device: 801h/2049d
```

To see why, read the [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
 specification very carefully.  Note that if you use one of the `1$` modifiers, you must (*should*) use it with every conversion specification.